# how to add attribute in an inline field Django?

Tags: javascript, python, django

When i try to add an attribute in an inline field, nothing added. I want a same class for each each select to add a javascript event on select change.

This is my models.py:

```
class Conversation(models.Model):
    conversation_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Nom du conversation", 
max_length=255)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, verbose_name="Groupe")

class ConversationMessage(models.Model):
    conversation_title = models.ForeignKey(Conversation, 
                         verbose_name="Conversation")
    from_message = models.ForeignKey(MessageList, verbose_name="De", 
                   related_name="from_message")
    to_message = models.ForeignKey(MessageList, verbose_name="A", 
                 related_name="to_message")
```

my admin.py:

```
class ConversationMessageInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ConversationMessage`

class ConversationMessageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ConversationMessageForm
    list_display = ['conversation_title', 'from_message', 'to_message']

class ConversationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ConversationForm
    list_display = ['conversation_name']
    inlines = [
        ConversationMessageInline,
    ]
```

my forms.py:

```
class ConversationMessageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = ConversationMessage
    from_message = forms.ModelChoiceField(MessageList.objects.all(),
                                   widget=forms.Select(attrs=
                                     {"onChange":'refresh()'}))
    class Media:
        js = ('js/forms_event.js',)

class ConversationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = Conversation
    class Media:
        js = ('js/forms_event.js',)
```

my forms_event.js:

```
function refresh() {
    alert("salut la planete");
}
```

The event onchange didn't added when I'm at "Add Conversation":

[image]

Comment: "onChange" or "onchange" ?

Answer (score 1):

You Just need to override the default form of the Inline class and add you new form to the TabularInline Class, as the following:

```
class ConversationMessageInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ConversationMessage
    form = ConversationMessageForm
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's a bad practice to mix python and javascript, so don't embed scripts in your forms.

Instead, you could just do something like this in your .js file:

```
var from_message_field = document.getElementById('<id of the field>');
from_message_field.addEventListener('change', refresh);
```